# In Webpack 3 how can I generate a different CSS URL when built?

Tags: webpack, css-loader, sass-loader

I am trying to output a different URL for my background images when my project is built.

My current CSS image path is:

`./src/components/assets/images....`

What I want when built:

`/images/default-source/images/icon.png`

I have tried different things such as options within the `css-loader` but none of them have worked. Usually, it will cause a problem when running the project as It can't find the images.

**Directories:**

`/build/main.css`
`/src/components/assets/css/main.css`
`/src/components/assets/images/`

`/webpack.config.js`

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { 
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { 
          url: false ,
        }
      },
      { 
        loader: 'postcss-loader' 
      },
      { 
        loader: 'sass-loader',
      },
    ],
  }),
},
```

I have thought maybe using some sort of find and replace during the build. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this on your webpack.config.js or during the build of your app

```
npm run build --output-public-path='/images/default-source/'
```

No sure if webpack 3 still accept didn't tested, regards

Comment: Thanks for the response. It did work, but wasn't exactly what I needed. I was able to achieve what I wanted through the use of an Alias and moving my images to the root of the App. Not sure if this the best method but it seems to work.

Comment: It can be a little bit more secure lol. you can also add a shell script after the build to mv /source /destination